# Reversing an integer-converted datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL the function

```
CONVERT(INT, GETDATE())
```

returns an integer like `43110`.

Is there any way to reverse this function and roll back the `43110` value to the original `datetime` format?

Comment: You may be able to get the date portion, however, the time portion will have been truncated during the conversion.

Comment: Ty, OlafW completed your answer bottom by suggesting a float conversion instead of the integer conversion of my datetime. Appreciated anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, 43110)
```

to get the datetime back - but your former

```
CONVERT(INT, GETDATE())
```

has been rounded - it should have been something about 43109.625

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 43109.625)
```

Best way would be to use

```
SELECT (CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE()))
```

for retrieving the decimal representation.

Comment: Thanks.. and sorry for the noob question, i was trying to reverse it by using the DATE format instead of DATETIME, and that produced an error :S

Answer (score 1):

This will return the date portion only:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, 43110)
```

If you need the time portion too, then use `FLOAT` instead of `INTEGER`:

```
CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE()) -- results in a number like 43109.6431769676
```

and back:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, 43109.6431769676)
```